# Why `\n` doesn't move the text to next line in R?

Tags: r, plot, character

I was wondering in my `bquote()` code below, why even though I use `\n` the text after `\n` doesn't go to the next line?

```
g <- 5
main = bquote(bold("mean effect ("*mu*")"*"\n of"~.(g)~"studies"))
plot(1, main = main)
```

Comment: You can use `atop` ie. `main = bquote(bold(atop("mean effect ("*mu*")")~"of"~.(g)~"studies"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `atop` instead of `\n`

```
main <- bquote(bold(atop("mean effect ("*mu*")", "of"~.(g)~"studies"~phantom(100))))
plot(1, main = main)
```

Comment: @Reza The vertical spacing is a bit difficult within thee `main`